# Angular app cannot be accessed on webserver without prefix "www"

Tags: angular, cpanel, no-www

i just deploying my first website with angular. the name of my website is

```
https://www.swargaflowertea.com.
```

it was a regular website tbh and nothing fancy. i have a problem when i tried to access my site with or without Schema "www".

if i try to access it without "www" like this :

```
https://swargaflowertea.com
```

it will giving null result (no data rendered and just a simple background).

the way i build it is by using this command

```
ng build --baseHref=https://www.swargaflowertea.com/ --deployUrl=https://www.swargaflowertea.com/
```

my site's has hashing routes.

mind anyone would know what's going on. thanks in advance

**PS**

- My site's hosted with a shared hosting based on centos 7.
- I am running on Angular12
- I've tried to edit baseHref prefix in my index.html from https://www.swargaflowertea.com/ to https://swargaflowertea.com and it still giving me the same result (vice versa)

just tell me the required data and i'll be happy to provide it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!. i just need to configure cPanel to redirect https://swargaflowertea.com/ to https://www.swargaflowertea.com/

that's all i have to do ...